# Can I call these member functions of std::unordered_map concurrently?

Tags: c++, multithreading, std, unordered-map

I have a global `std::unordered_map<int, int> m`.
I also have exactly one thread that is type A and multiple threads are type B running concurrently.

Thread type A:
call `insert()`, `erase()` to add/remove some elements (guarantee not the elements read/write in the thread type B concurrently) of m

Thread type B:
call `operator[]` of m, do something like `m[key] = value`.  (guarantee thread type B will not modify the same element concurrently, and the key exists in `m` already)

Is it safe to do these operations concurrently without a lock?

Comment: Doing insertion can cause rehashing. This alone makes it obvious that it's not safe.

Comment: If the keys are all different, why can't you have two maps `m_a` in thread A, and `m_b` for all your threads `B`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) can rehash the array which reallocates the bucket array. If that happens right before `operator[]` accesses it, that's a use-after-free.

This probably isn't the only reason it's unsafe, but we only have to find one, to prove that it's unsafe.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not safe. None of the methods of `std::unordered_map`, nor any other container in the C++ library, are thread safe. Therefore if one execution thread is modifying the container, all access to the container, from all execution threads, must be properly synchronized.

Comment: Does the standard say explicitly that they're not thread safe, or must we just assume so since it doesn't mention thread safety?

Comment: This is too strong. There are certain [guarantees](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Thread_safety), e.g. "different elements in the same container can be modified concurrently by different threads, except for the elements of `std::vector<bool>`."

Comment: There are scenarios where concurrent access to a container is safe - mostly, when no thread is modifying the container itself but rather only the elements in it.